# Icon as Integer and Integer to Icon

Tags: flutter

I need to save an `Icon` as an `int` and later convert it back to an `Icon`. I thought I can achieve this with the icon's `codePoint`; `IconData` takes a parameter `codePoint` in the constructor but the following does not work:

`Icon(IconData(Icons.person.codePoint))`

The icon is some Chinese sign, not the actual person icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to pass back in the font, for example:

```
  Icon(IconData(Icons.person.codePoint, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'));
```